# Which is better for returning resultset from an oracle database => Ref. Cursor vs Select sql statement

Tags: oracle

I have been googling for a while to find an alternative approach for returning a resultset rather than returning a ref cursor but failed to find it so. As i have done most of my development in sql server where we won't use cursors unless until it is necessary but i understand it differs from ref. cursor. But on top of that when we return a ref. cursor as an output from database it will become a connected architecture. So my dear Geeks can you answer/clear my confusions as mentioned below,

1. I want to understand which is the better way for returning a result set to our application (Ref. cursor or SELECT statement with all the joins or any other options)?
2. Is using ref. cursor is a connected /disconnected architecture?
3. Is using Select sql query is better for a disconnected approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As usual, it depends on your needs.

Regarding connected /disconnected architecture it makes almost no difference. After your client application received the RefCursor and all rows are fetched (and preferably the cursor is closed) you can disconnect and reconnect from database the same way as using direct SELECT statement.

Consider following pseudo-code examples:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT_NAME  
FROM EMP
    JOIN DEPT ON EMP_DEPT_ID = DEPT_ID
WHERE DEPT_ID = :d;

vs. 

CREATE FUNCTION GetEmps(deptId IN NUMBER) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
   res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN res FOR
   SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT_NAME  
   FROM EMP
       JOIN DEPT ON EMP_DEPT_ID = DEPT_ID
   WHERE DEPT_ID = deptId;
   RETURN res;
END;
```

My personal favorite is to prefer a RefCursors because:

- With RefCursor client and server are more separated from each other, i.e. the client just has to know the function name and which attributes he receives (`EMP_NAME`and `DEPT_NAME`), nothing else. He does not have to know the table names or any join condition. Developers of client and server can work more independently from each other.
- With RefCursor you can implement fine-granularity security methods. You only have to do `grant execute on GetEmps to ...` and the client gets EMP_NAME and DEPT_NAME - no more, no less! 
  With direct SELECT you have to grant select on both tables, however then the client could also execute `SELECT SALARY, EMP_NAME FROM EMP;` for instance (unless you use the quite expensive VPD feature from Oracle). If you like you can log every single call of the function and add as many constraints as you like.
- with RefCursor the client application (and not the server) can decide how many rows he like to fetch in order to optimize response times.

Answer (score 0):

the basic difference is that when you are uncertain about the sql query you are going to execute at run time, then use ref cursor and you can use same ref cursor for different sql queries. for example
for query

```
select name,id,dob from table where id=:v_id;
```

here v_id is passed at run time, so we can use ref cursor. v_id varies at run time.

While the select statement is used in for each loop when we have small set of records. When we have large set of records we can use bulk collect with ref cursor and limit rows.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, all DML statements are cursors. A cursor is simply a set of instructions used by the optimizer to get to the data.

In my Oracle-centric opinion, everything that is done in the database should be done in stored procedures, so that you have a central interface into the database - ie. if you had two applications updating/retrieving data to/from the same database, you'd only need one set of stored procs on the database, rather than replicating the logic twice in each application.

With that in mind, ref cursors are the way to go.

However, if you're not going down that route (boo! *{;-) ) there is little difference between a ref cursor and a straight select statement in terms of getting the data to the front end. How you call for the data will be different, of course, but it's the same thing to the database.

All a ref cursor does is basically hold a pointer to a cursor.